# How to set a LaTeX3 variable to the value of a LaTeX3 expression that evaluates to a control sequene?

Tags: latex3

I'd like to set the control sequence `\my_cs` to the value of some LaTeX3 expression that expands to a control sequence, e.g. to the value of

```
\use:c {some_other_control_sequence}
```

In other words, `\some_other_control_sequence` is an existing control sequence that is set to some value, and I'd like to set `\my_cs` to this value, but without writing out the control sequence `\some_other_control_sequence` explicitly. How can I do so?

For instance, suppose `\some_other_control_sequence` is a global LaTeX3 variable set to the integer `42`, and suppose I'm writing a LaTeX3 function, and the name of this variable, namely `some_other_control_sequence` is expected to be passed in as the parameter `#1`, but I don't know the name of this variable at the time of writing the function. How can I set `\my_cs` to `\some_other_control_sequence`'s value, namely `42`, inside the function that I'm writing?

Comment: If it is 'set to some value' presumably it's a variable, or is this a function? Also the `\use:c` implies the name is constructed on-the-fly: is that the case or it is known in advance?

Comment: @JosephWright: It is a variable.

Comment: @JosephWright: It is constructed on-the-fly.

Comment: Sounds (but I wouldn't bet on it) as if you are looking for `\cs_set_eq:cc {my_cs}{#1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the variable typs in `expl3` has a series of `set_eq` functions for this task, for example

```
\tl_set_eq:NN \l_my_new_tl \l_my_old_tl
\seq_set_eq:Nc \l_my_new_seq { g_my_old_seq }
\dim_gset_eq:cc { g_my_new_dim } { l_my_old_dim }
```

Notice that both `N`- and `c`-type arguments may be used and that the scope should be correct for the variable being set.